# String contains only the alphabet in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, character, alphabet, letter

I want to make a functions which decides wheter the character is a letter in the alphabet in Haskell

```
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
```

So the outcome may look like this: if I type `isLetter 'c'`, the outcome will be `True`, and if it's `isLetter ' '`, then the outcome is `False`.

Comment: Good luck with making that function :) What is the question?

Comment: The question is how can i define that a string or a character is contain something in haskell?

Comment: By writing a function.

Comment: Please show some effort. For example present a *conceptual* algorithm, or parts that you managed to implement. Explain what is not working with your attempt.

Comment: When asking a question please make it clear what your problem at hand is, not the overall task or project you are doing. When it's done please take another look at the question and think if the answer could be easily found in documentation. If the answer is Yes maybe there is no point in posting a question. Cheers. :)

Comment: I'm really sorry my english is not that good. I'm a freshman at the UNI. 
And my task was to write one function which decides the string/character if it is one of the alphabet, the outcome may be true of false.
But the problem is i do not know which of the functions should i use for contain. 
Something like that:
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
isLetter n = ['a..Z'] == n

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. FWIW, people aren't complaining about your English, but rather that it's not clear what your question is. ATM, it looks as though your question is *please write the code for me*, which most regulars here discourage; this is a Q&A site, not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define this function yourself,

```
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
isLetter 'A' = True
isLetter 'B' = True
...
isLetter 'Z' = True
```

But what about lowercase letters? What about foreign letters like `'ß'`, `'ü'`, `'Ф'`, `'Й'` or `'Æ'` and their uppercase/lowercase variants? Because Unicode is so complex, for any production-level use you should depend on already built library functions. When you don't know what they're called, [go to Hoogle and search for "`Char -> Bool`"](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Bool) and you'll often be pointed to a library that contains exactly what you want. :-)

For example, the documentation for `Data.Char.isAlpha` says:

> Selects alphabetic Unicode characters (lower-case, upper-case and title-case letters, plus letters of caseless scripts and modifiers letters). **This function is equivalent to `Data.Char.isLetter`.**

I bet you didn't think of *title-case letters*, *letters of caseless scripts* and *modifier letters*! (I didn't.)

I didn't even know *modifier letters* existed. Apparently, [`'ˀ'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop_(letter)) (glottal stop) is a letter used by the [Squamish people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squamish_language) of southwestern British Columbia, Canada. There are Canadian road signs out there that your function isn't taking into account!

Are you gonna be the guy who tells Ḇøᵇ that he can't get on the plane?! :Đ

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, the people (linguists?) who devised the writing system used "ˀ", but because that wasn't available on typewriters or in typical pre-Unicode encodings, it's conventionally written "7". So the numeral 7 is also a letter in Sḵwx̱wú7mesh sníchim, which really messes with rigid notions of classification!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Data.Char.isAlpha` to check that character is alphabet symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.

```
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
isLetter c = (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `elem` function and ranges to see if a character is a letter or not. Notice that the range  `['a'..'z']` contains all the letters from **a** to **z** in a list. Likewise, the range `['A'..'Z']`is a list that contains all the uppercase letters. So, the function will check if the given character belongs to any of these lists and if it does, it returns `True`; otherwise, it returns `False`.

```
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
isLetter character = if character `elem` ['a'..'z'] || character `elem` ['A'..'Z']
                     then True
                     else False
```